# The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, mysql

i have this error in my code and i'm a beginner i don't know why in other programs the action event/ action performed on click is successful but in this one i used it the same pattern and it gives me this error , can someone help me ?

The error takes place through the createfirstframe class when i try to put an event when the user click on login

```
package cinema;


import java.awt.*;

import java.sql.*;

import javax.swing.*;


//Create a simple GUI window 

public class createframe {
    
    public static void createfirstframe() {
            JFrame Frame1;
        
    
            
            Frame1 = new JFrame("Customer");

            Frame1.setSize(1000,1000);

            Frame1.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2));
            
            JLabel login1= new JLabel("      Type your IDs to log in the Cinema interface !");
            Frame1.add(login1);
            JTextField logintextarea1 = new JTextField(30);
            JPasswordField loginpassword1 = new JPasswordField("");
            JLabel login = new JLabel("Login customer (pseudo) : ");
            
            JLabel password= new JLabel("password : ");
            Frame1.add(login);
            Frame1.add(logintextarea1);
            
            Frame1.add(password);
            Frame1.add(loginpassword1);
            Frame1.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/Users/elouazraouiayoub/Downloads/AtTheMovies.jpg")));
            
            
            JButton btnGet = new JButton("Log in");
            Frame1.add(btnGet);
            
            btnGet.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
                    try {
                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                        Connection c= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/test","root","");
                        Statement stmt =c.createStatement();
                        String sql="Select * from usersID where Username='"+logintextarea1.getText()+"' and password='"+loginpassword1.getText()+"'";
                        ResultSet rs =stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                        if(rs.next())
                        {
                    //connexion and checking established
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username/password Error","ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        logintextarea1.setText(null);
                        loginpassword1.setText(null);
                        logintextarea1.requestFocusInWindow();
                        }
                        }
                    
                        catch (Exception e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}
            
                    
            Frame1.setVisible(true);
            
            
            
            
                                                            }});
    }
        
    public static void createsecondframe()
    
                                    {
        
        JFrame Frame2;
            Frame2 = new JFrame("employee");

            Frame2.setSize(1000,1000);

            Frame2.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2));
            
            JLabel login2= new JLabel("      Type your employee IDs to log in the Cinema interface !");
            Frame2.add(login2);
            JTextField logintextarea2 = new JTextField(30);
            JPasswordField loginpassword2 = new JPasswordField("");
            JLabel login = new JLabel("Login employee (pseudo) : ");
            
            JLabel password= new JLabel("password : ");
            Frame2.add(login);
            Frame2.add(logintextarea2);
            
            Frame2.add(password);
            Frame2.add(loginpassword2);
            Frame2.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/Users/elouazraouiayoub/Downloads/AtTheMovies.jpg")));
            Frame2.setVisible(true);
            
            
                                    }}
```

this is my class program

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try importing

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
```

at the begining and run it again.